# A Roswell damage control

Tags: aliens

An alien ship crashlands and the it is not completely unrecoverable. Unfortunatelly locals and the police, as well as some camera crews arrive at the scene before my intelligence agency does, so enough pictures and videos are taken before us having time to come up with an alternative explanation.

After talking to the head of the agency, I make a plan to pretend that the ship is a clever Hollywood prop. I know pictures were taken, and people have been on the site, so I decide to cordon the area and allow the press, but tax the private citizens who want to take pictures of the UFO (30 dollars for a picture). At the same time, I start building a lab around the crash site, without offering much of an explanation on what I am doing. Finally, I bring a famous Hollywood director whose upcoming science fiction movie I am financing to take over the science building and start filming on his movie. I also offer no explanation, but I allow the press to ask the director's cast and crew whatever questions they like. I also continue to allow the press to take pictures of the site and of the newly built facility.

In the online environmnent I use my trolls and chat bots from the agency to launch various contradictory rumors about the crash and the upcoming movie of my friendly director.

Would this strategy work to bury my alien event in a sea of irrelevant information and remove it from the spotlight, until I can finish my analysis of the alien objects?

Comment: Will it work? That's a plot choice you have to make.

Comment: VTC:Too Story-Based. Per the [help/on-topic], `When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story` and `If ... you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site.`

Comment: Ship everyone off to black sites, or threaten to do so if they talk. 72 hours of sleep deprivation, and government officials screaming at them they'll be hanged as traitors if they talk can shut most people up. Confiscate everything, it's not the digital age yet so no tv producer will be hiding a USB fob up his butt. Monitor the population of this small town for the next 30 years. Trying to be clever only gives dedicated spies more to investigate and work through, not less.

Comment: What is this "Agency" that you mention? Apparently it has the authority to tax people. Your strategy depends on a certain amount of power that you are wielding. It seems the viability of your strategy is dependent on the amount of authority your agency has.

Comment: In what era is this taking place?  It'd be really hard to fabricate a paper trail for financing a sci-fi film out of nowhere in the modern day, when IMDB et al dig into these things.

Comment: Not in the real world. The odds of keeping a secret is the inverse of an exponential function of the number of people anywhere near it. This is especially true of Hollywood types, who are self-selected to have more attention seeking behavior than concern for their safety.

Comment: this question has been closed abusively.

Comment: @user3653831 Rather than accusing people of being "abusive", it might be more productive to engage with those who voted to close it, and particularly with JBH who left a link to and quote from the [help] a few days ago. It may be that you can [edit] the question to remove their concerns about its suitability for the site, or explain to them why you think they've misunderstood the question, or the rules they're quoting.

Comment: @IMSoP sorry, I got annoyed because there is a story, but I couldn't see the relevance of posting it here. I also didn't see the point to jump through hoops to reopen the question, since it was already buried. Maybe I'm wrong, but the format of the site and its rules simply don't work for me anymore.

Answer (score 4):

### Don't underestimate the power of a lying en-masse

I would not bother with the whole movie thing, that brings in too many witnesses and creates too many dubious paper trails.  Just call it hoax and lie until people believe you.  Focus instead on just this:

> In the online environment I use my trolls and chat bots from the agency to launch various contradictory rumors about the crash...

You of course can't convince everyone that a thing is made up, but you can convince most people that anything is a hoax just by saying it is in enough places.  99.999% of the people in your country were not actually there.  99.99% of people don't even know anyone who was there.  So, for most people, this becomes a case of he-said she-said.  Due to how good CGI has gotten, videos and photos are no longer considered proof of a thing.  When most people see an outrageous photo, no matter how realistic it may seem, we automatically assume now that it is a fake.

To push this natural skepticism, the government could download real videos, CG them to create artifacts of manipulation and re-circulate them to anti-hoax influencers to rip apart.  You can pay off a local farmer to confess it was just a prank he pulled on the local news station that got out of hand... or better yet, just publish articles about a local farmer confessing.  Said prankster does not need to actually exist to satisfy most people's wiliness to disbelieve something.  Have chat bots talk about knowing people involved in the hoax and link to your misdirects anywhere people are talking about the real facts.

With enough lies that line up well enough with truths, you can even create false memories convincing many of the people who were there that they saw things they only saw in your hoax videos or that they did not see things that they actually did.  Human memory is so unreliable that if you show people doing things that they did not actually do, most people will create new memories around those lies.  So even actual witnesses will eventually will start to buy into your false narratives.

Then as further research is done into the events of the day, witness testimonies and evidence will all be such a mess of conflicting details, that no reasonable person will believe any of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** build a lab there. Just have the government deny any knowledge, and as the speculation hits overdrive start an "obfuscating" ad campaign.

- *"You only thought you knew."* With a minimalistic outline of the crashed UFO, and *no* hint what this is about. Digging into the money trail will find links to a big media company, which denies any knowledge in an *obviously* lawyer-approved way.
- A month later: *"You only thought you knew. In cinemas this summer."* With a slightly more detailed drawing of the crash site.
- Another month later: *"You only thought you knew.* <insert name of town> *In cinemas this summer.*" With the UFO and some big-name stars on it.

In a saturated *advertising* environment, people have to be different to get noticed. One method is to trigger the curiosity of the readers, similar to [clickbait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait) web content.

For added fun, have someone "try to" sue the studio because they "stole" the look and feel of the UFO and the plot from an unsolicited submission.

But **don't** do too much that could lead to a government connection. Like the lab, or the systematic spreading of confusion. Various analysts are tracking trends in disinformation these days, and *"it is always the cover-up that gets you caught."*

Answer (score 2):

**Frame Challenge**

If you have the Internet in your scenario, then all you can do is attempt to close the barn door after the horse has bolted.

Let's consider the actors at play here:

1: The people who will *always* believe a conspiracy theory - no matter what the Government says, they will think you are lying

2: The people who will *always* believe the Government - 'Nuff Said.

3: The 'Normies' - that is, regular people who have a healthy distrust of the Government and a healthy skepticism about wild leaps of logic.

Now, in recent times - I can think a number of notable events that have generated significant discussion:

September 11th. The 2020 Election. The origin of Covid.

Without declaring a side on any of these issues - you have the same 3 factions.

For example: There are people who absolutely believe that 9/11 was an inside job. There are people who absolutely believe that everything is as the Govt says it was. Most people think it was a terrorist attack - but that there a few coincidences that raise suspicion.

Now, going back to historical theories - you've got the theory about drugging soldiers (MK Ultra), of the FBI doing FBI things to the Black Panthers and other groups and you have McCarthy being proved correct after the fall of the Soviet Union.

Same groups.

Going through an elaborate ruse, in the Internet age, where the 4chan-esque weaponized aut... who will quite happily dredge through thousands of obscure documents just to try and prove you wrong is going to arouse more suspicion than it's going to quash.

It would be better then, to try and act as indifferent and as Business-as-Usual as possible. Experimental testbed aircraft crashed, just a routine recovery job to protect classified technologies.

And then let the Internet rumour mill do all the things that you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this strategy work to bury my alien event in a sea of irrelevant information and remove it from the spotlight, until I can finish my analysis of the alien objects?

Insufficient information for a meaningful answer. But ultimately, you wouldn't be able to stop chatter about it forever. That's why a lot of national secrets and classified information tends to be rated based on how long it will take to leak, rather than based on the possibility of it never happening.

It also depends on how information is able to spread. After the invention of the internet, it would have no chance of escaping public notice, especially if you were late to the party.

> After talking to the head of the agency, I make a plan to pretend that the ship is a clever Hollywood prop. I know pictures were taken, and people have been on the site, so I decide to cordon the area and allow the press, but tax the private citizens who want to take pictures of the UFO (30 dollars for a picture). At the same time, I start building a lab around the crash site, without offering much of an explanation on what I am doing. Finally, I bring a famous Hollywood director whose upcoming science fiction movie I am financing to take over the science building and start filming on his movie. I also offer no explanation, but I allow the press to ask the director's cast and crew whatever questions they like. I also continue to allow the press to take pictures of the site and of the newly built facility.

The issue here is that you would have people start wondering why you're building a lab around the hoax. Especially a secret one where no-one's talking about the reason for its existence.

If you're trying to pass it off as a hoax, or an advertisement, then most people would expect it to be removed/preserved, not for an organisation to start constructing a building around it for study, particularly not a new one. (and it would be disproven if people noticed the spacecraft crash-land)

Even with the film crew, it is highly irregular to build a set and stage around a prop after the fact. There would be questions.

---

If the alien ship contained no aliens, and/or could conceivably pass as something developed by your civilisation, you could pass it off as an experimental aircraft/spacecraft that went horribly wrong, and crashed after the pilot ejected (hence the lack of pilot).

The alien language is a now-leaked method of classifying information to prevent it from being stolen, etc.

You treat it as a massive intelligence disaster. A few governments/organisations might be a bit suspicious, but you can either get a few on your side (the military might be willing to help out if you can give them some of that juicy advanced alien tech), or at least use the excuse as a way to keep them quiet.

> In the online environmnent I use my trolls and chat bots from the agency to launch various contradictory rumors about the crash and the upcoming movie of my friendly director.

The [Batman method](https://screenrant.com/batman-identity-secret-trolling-internet-theory/) would work rather well, especially in conjunction with the above. You can discredit any particularly dedicated people as regular UFO conspiracists, leaping at the first hint of anything that could be alien, when there are far more reasonable, mundane explanations.

---

If there are any identifiable aliens or something that cannot be explained away, then the cat is out of the bag. It would be better to acknowledge the presence of aliens, and let it become old news than to hide it, and risk a furore when it's either eventually revealed, or leaked.

Just say that "we believe the craft to not be of local origin, and will be studying to determine whether there is any threat posed to us", or something along those lines. There might be a bunch of chatter and arguments over it, but it would eventually blow over.

Answer (score -3):

## The ship has sailed

[Most people believe in aliens](https://yougov.co.uk/topics/society/articles-reports/2015/09/24/you-are-not-alone-most-people-believe-aliens-exist), and are going to be actively interested in learning about the aliens. [The government has openly admitted to having non human crafts.](https://www.newsweek.com/ufo-uap-craft-found-covered-whistleblower-claims-1804733)

As such, while you could try and spread confusion, the majority of people who believe in aliens will likely believe it is so. People with good cameras will find that the alien ship has alloys or materials not from earth, and discover evidence that it is so.

And news agencies will actively cover this, till we move onto something new. It's not like they can naruto run and defeat armed soldiers, in time you'll cover it up or move it and move on.

Comment: "People with good cameras will find that the alien ship has alloys or materials not from earth" - I'm not convinced by this assertion. It would have to be something really weird to be obvious from a photo that it wasn't any of the thousands of different materials and finishes we've already come up with.